# How to prove that K is the range of inputs for O(n+K) time complexity for counting sort?

Tags: data-structures, time, time-complexity, theory, proof

How would one prove that K is the range of inputs? How would it be the same as the maximum element? Using geeksforgeeks as an reference where it said K is the range of inputs: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/. If I had an list of 5, 7, 6, what would be K?

My logic was if I had an list of 5, 7, 6. Then I make an array of 0 to 2: [0][1][2]. since the range is 5 to 7,  where all of the locations are just going to be stored at a place + the difference to the smallest number. Where I would store 0s and 1s for if a number is found or not. Then when I am retrieving values I always add the lowest number, which would be 5 in this scenario. In this case there would be a 0 at index 1 and a 1 at index 2. Adding 2 and 5 would arrive to make K: 7.

It feels like I am missing something.

Comment: *"How would it be the same as the maximum element?"*: where did you read it has to be the same?

Comment: Was something that was taught during my lecture. Wondering if it will arrive to the same answer with k being the range of inputs or the maximum element in the list?

Comment: When your input has negative values, than certainly K needs to be greater than the maximum element. K really is max(arr)-min(arr)+1.

Answer (score 0):

> How would one prove that K is the range of inputs? How would it be the same as the maximum element?

This  does not have to be the same as the maximum element. It can be smaller or greater.

> ...it said K is the range of inputs

This is true.

> If I had an list of 5, 7, 6, what would be K?

needs to be at least max(input) − min(input) + 1. In your example case, =3

> I make an array of 0 to 2: [0][1][2].

This is the correct approach, and it shows you need 3 slots, and this is exactly what  is about. You always want to map the input range to the range [0,...,−1].

> Adding 2 and 5 would arrive to make K: 7.

No, this is not related to . This is about the reverse mapping you need to perform from the [0,...,−1] range to the actual input range.

The time complexity is O(+) because the algorithm needs to iterate over the input values () and needs to iterate over the "buckets" (counters) in the range [0,...,−1]. If the input numbers are all distinct, then you could simplify and say the complexity is O(), as then ≤.